# Empty list of events while downloading data from Facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying do download information about events using Facebook in a Python code. Firstly I tried to extract all the events linked to "Rock". This is how the code looks like:

```
import urllib3
import facebook
import requests
token = "xyz"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token, version = 2.7)
events = graph.request('/search?q=Cinema&type=event&limit=10000')
print('Print if token O.K.')
eventList = events['data']
print('Everything is still ok.')
if len(eventList) != 0:
    print('Works.')
else:
    print('Something strange happened.')
```

The first string was printed so everything is alright with the token and the permission.
However the list is empty. I wonder why?
My second question is if it is possible to download events from a certain city only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Searching for events is not possible anymore.

Comment: That's a pity! I wonder why even public events cannot be searched anymore.

Comment: for privacy reasons, i guess. no one really knows.

Comment: Using a Page Access Token for my own page in an app in development mode the /page/events endpoint also returns empty data. It needs an app review. But my app is still in test mode?!

Comment: this is horrible news thanks for the answer @luschn otherwise i wouldn't know that